# Is there software which detects Youtube/Soundcloud audio quality/volume?

Tags: music, audio, youtube, comparison, file-format

I am in the process of setting up Nightbot for use in a Twitch stream. My goal is to build a "Personal Playlist," which is a music library derived from a combination of Youtube and Soundcloud links. My questions relate to criteria for choosing which Youtube or Soundcloud link should be used when multiple are available for the same song (whether Youtube VS Youtube, Soundcloud VS Soundcloud, or Youtube VS Soundcloud).

1) As far as I can see neither Youtube nor Soundcloud explicitly labels the audio quality of videos/songs anywhere. Is there a simple, external tool used to measure this audio quality (either by detecting the audio format, or the specific audio metrics)?

2) Is there any simple way to measure the average volume of one video/song to compare it to another, in order to avert the later annoyance of one song playing too quiet, and the next too loud? This would be difficult to approximate by ear when building a collection over the span of many days.  There are many programs with graphs which measure the output volume at each instant, but in order to compare the volume of one song to another, it seems that an aggregate value, such as an average, would need to be used.

Comment: Nothing guarantees that the quality returned by the service is correct. Let's assume that a service allows to upload lossless (FLAC?) audio, and I upload some crap MP3 converted to FLAC. It'll still be labeled as FLAC by the service, but will be nowhere near the quality of a real FLAC file. Your only reliable solution would be to download a sample of the file and then analyze it with some custom code you write. See http://www.maurits.vdschee.nl/fakeflac/

Comment: @AndréDaniel Unfortunately, I don't think downloading each file would be practical, so unless another suggestion can be offered, I might have to just do the best I can with quality.  Still looking for a suggestion for objectively measuring aggregate volume.